# google checkout android payment?

Tags: android, google-checkout

I am building a shopping cart application for android. My customers already have google checkout merchants accounts and they want to sell their goods and receive payments in their google checkout merchants accounts.

I have an activity that displays user-selected goods and payment. I need to know what is the info I'll send to google and service links that can make the app users pay for selected goods in merchants account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not clear enough, but this might help you:

http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_Custom_Processing_How_To.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_overview.html

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to implement an Android native app and not a web app. You may want to start with the Android In-App Billing documentation:

http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/index.html

Also please make to read the Android Market Developer Distribution Agreement:

http://www.android.com/us/developer-distribution-agreement.html